# Problem iN XML schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I am I thinking right? Do I need to put any restrictions here if I use simpletype? Console has alues like ABc, pjs, hefgehw,...like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to limit values for `console`, `maker`. See [XSD Restrictions/Facets](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_facets.asp). Also, `number` cannot have negative values. Everything else is OK, I think.

#### update:

```
...
<xs:element name="gaming-platform">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="console" use="required">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="XBox"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="PSP"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="maker" use="required">
      ...
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="ninstock" use="required">
      ...
    </xs:attribute>
    
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: U want me to use maxinclusive and mininclusive? BUt If i dont use these..then by default, its value is 1 which I should get.

Comment: I didn't get your question. If you don't use boundaries for `xsd:integer`, it can be any integer, but "number of items in stock" cannot be negative.

Comment: Oh yes....actually, I wanted to know that there is written 1 occurance in every case? what should I do with that??

Comment: How do I deal with 1 occurance?

Comment: if I dont know the name of the console like xbox and psp...then I should directly use type xs:string. Right?

Comment: Right. Use restrictions if any.

Comment: please help me in this question....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177684/xml-schema-doubt