# XML schema Doubt!

Tags: xml, xsd

```
Could any one tell me how to do this? i need to change it into **xml schema**. The problem that I am facing is that I can't think of where to use elements and wehere to use attributes.
```

IF i consider these as attributes:`<xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>**`  - i will use this statement. But then where do I make use of occurances. It can only be done with elements?Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want `Name` and `Phone` to appear in order, you must use elements, since the order of attributes in XML documents is (per the XML recommendation) not significant.

Your schema should look (in outline) something like:

```
<xs:element name="RetailerRequest">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Name"
                  minOccurs="1"
                  maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element ref="RetailerContact"
                  minOccurs="1"
                  maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="RetailerContact">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Name"
                  minOccurs="1"
                  maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="Phone"
                  minOccurs="1"
                  maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```